# Django: Modify database object on click using a ListView

Tags: python, html, django, database, django-templates

I have a ListView that I use to display a list of products. On the right of every product/row, I want a "archive" button that, when clicked-on, will change the "archived" field of the product in the database from True to False.  
I'd like to do this using only Django and I think this is possible but I have a hard time finding out how. 
I'm trying to do it using a form, but I don't know how I can send the pk of the current object (in the loop) back to the view to make the change. 
Here's my template (the relevant part):

```
{% for product in product_list %}
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">{{ product.pk }}</th>
                  <td>
                    <a href="{% url 'accounts:products_edit' pk=product.pk %}">
                      {{ product.title }}</a
                    >
                  </td>
                
                  <td class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <form action="" method="POST">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                      <button type="submit"><i class="fas fa-trash" style="color: grey"></i></button>
                    </form>
                  </td>
                </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Here's my view:

```
class ProductsListView(ListView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    template_name = "accounts/products/products_list.html"
    model = Product

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # ...
   
        return context
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # modify object from pk here
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)
```

I've seen several post with similar situations, but didn't find a solution that works completely for my case. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to have a new endpoint
`accounts/products/archive/{productPk}` {productPk} being the PK of the product to archive
This has 2 benefits vs the form approach
1.That endpoint is reusable across your views with simpler calls and not using multiple forms
2.If you decide to have an API alongside your FE, you already have the archive action done, with your approach you would have to create multiple ways to archive

Coding the POST request itself is pretty straightforward based on the code you already have, just make sure all proper validations exist on the new endpoint

EDIT - more information
Create a new view that receives the PK as an argument

```
def archive_product(request, archive_pk):
    # Rest of the method
```

Add a new url path with a path parameter (django uses regex for that)

```
path(r'^accounts/products/archive/(?P<product_pk>\d{0,50})/$', views.archive_product)
```

Change your JS code to call this new URL instead of submitting a form, here you will have to code this on your own since my JS knowledge is a bit more limited to give at least almost working code

The django code is based on the docs since i didn't want to create a new project for this.  The code should already exist in your current view or is pretty simple to write

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but could you elaborate a bit / show some code? I'm still pretty new to Django and web in general so I'm not sure I fully understand.

Comment: I don't know JS, that's why I said I'd like to use only Django (and html)

Comment: if you really don't want to use JS you can change the form action to the new url, i believe the form sends the fields as the request body so the logic might a bit different then when using the path parameter
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: Ok thanks I will try that. Though I wish there was a way to do it while staying on the same page

Comment: As far as i know, staying on the same page will require you to use JS. It would be wise to start experimenting with basic JS while doing FE development